# Trying to transform words in an array and output them onto the page, using forEach method, but each entry overwrites the previous item?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to wrap the words that are entered into the text area, by splitting them into an array, and using the foreach method to wrap each word in different keyword styles. Which all works in the console. But when I try and output it onto the DOM, it only displays the LAST item in the array, as they are overwriting the previous items... I might be going about it the wrong way, open to suggestions for re-factoring.

For example:

If you type in
'mens shoes, cheap mens shoes, affordable mens shoes'

It only displays: +affordable +mens +shoes.

I want it to display all of them in the new format.

```js
const mainInput = document.getElementById('main-input');
const mainOutput = document.getElementById('main-output');
let keywordsArray;

mainInput.addEventListener('input', updateValue);

function updateValue(e) {
  const mainInput = document.getElementById('main-input');
  const mainOutput = document.getElementById('main-output');
  keywordsArray = mainInput.value.split('\n');

  keywordsArray.forEach(textUpdater);

  function textUpdater(item, index, array) {
    console.log(item)
    console.log(item.replace(/(^|\s+)/g, "$1+"))
    console.log('[' + item + ']');
    console.log('"' + item + '"');
    mainOutput.innerText = '[' + item + ']';

  };
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="input-box">

    <textarea name="main-input" id="main-input" class="main-input" cols="30" rows="10" placeholder="Enter Keywords Here..."></textarea>

    <p>What match types?</p>
    <div class="type-selectors">
      <p>Broad:</p> <input type="checkbox" id="broadCheck" checked onclick="updateValue()">

      <p>Modified:</p> <input type="checkbox" id="modifiedCheck" checked onclick="updateValue()">

      <p>Phrase:</p> <input type="checkbox" id="phraseCheck" checked onclick="updateValue()">

      <p>Exact:</p> <input type="checkbox" id="exactCheck" checked onclick="updateValue()">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="output-box">
    <textarea class="main-output" id="main-output"></textarea>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `+=` to append text instead of overwriting the previous text. Moreover, you should set the value of the textarea instead of it's `innerText`.

```
mainOutput.innerText = '[' + item + ']';
```

Should be changed to:

```
mainOutput.value += '[' + item + ']';
```

```js
const mainInput = document.getElementById('main-input');
const mainOutput = document.getElementById('main-output');
let keywordsArray;

mainInput.addEventListener('input', updateValue);

function updateValue(e) {
  const mainInput = document.getElementById('main-input');
  const mainOutput = document.getElementById('main-output');
  keywordsArray = mainInput.value.split('\n');

  keywordsArray.forEach(textUpdater);

  function textUpdater(item, index, array) {
    //console.log(item)
    //console.log(item.replace(/(^|\s+)/g, "$1+"))
    //console.log('[' + item + ']');
    //console.log('"' + item + '"');
    mainOutput.value += '[' + item + ']';

  };
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="input-box">

    <textarea name="main-input" id="main-input" class="main-input" cols="30" rows="10" placeholder="Enter Keywords Here..."></textarea>

    <p>What match types?</p>
    <div class="type-selectors">
      <p>Broad:</p> <input type="checkbox" id="broadCheck" checked onclick="updateValue()">

      <p>Modified:</p> <input type="checkbox" id="modifiedCheck" checked onclick="updateValue()">

      <p>Phrase:</p> <input type="checkbox" id="phraseCheck" checked onclick="updateValue()">

      <p>Exact:</p> <input type="checkbox" id="exactCheck" checked onclick="updateValue()">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="output-box">
    <textarea class="main-output" id="main-output"></textarea>
  </div>

</div>
```